# jquery.each function duplicates items for each iteration

Tags: jquery, json

I'm getting a bunch of data from a JSON file that I display on a page and everything works great except that each item looped over gets duplicated for every iteration.

I know this is something silly but my googling is not working today so I can't find an answer.
When I log the block variable I get the response I am looking for but as I mentioned, it gets duplicated when I append the data so the problem must lie there.

Thanks for any help.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status) {

            $('#tp-header h2').html(data.TrustScore.Human);
            $('#tp-header img').attr('src', data.TrustScore.StarsImageUrls.large);
            $('#tp-header span').html(data.ReviewCount.Total);

                $.each(data.Reviews, function(key, val) {
                    var me = this;
                    $.each(val, function(i, j) {
                        var stars = me.TrustScore.StarsImageUrls.small;
                        var date = me.Created.HumanDate;
                        var title = me.Title;
                        var content = me.Content;
                        var avatar = me.User.ImageUrls.i24;
                        var name = me.User.Name;

                        var block = '<div class="review">' +
                                        '<div class="stars"><img src="' + stars + '" class="stars" /></div>' +
                                        '<div class="date">' + date + '</div>' +
                                        '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
                                        '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' +
                                        '<p>' + content + '</p>' +
                                        '<div class="profile"><i><img src="' + avatar + '" /></i>' +
                                        '<span>' + name + '</span>' +
                                        '</div></div>';

                        $(block).appendTo('#tp-body');

                    });


                });

        },
        error: function(XHR, txtStatus, errThrown) {
            console.log('Error: ' + txtStatus);
            console.log('Error: ' + errThrown);
        }
    });
```

JSON snippet

```
{
"Categories":[ ],
"DomainName":"company.net",
"FeedUpdateTime":{ },
"ReviewCount":{ },
"ReviewPageUrl":"http://example.com",
"Reviews":[
  {
     "Created":{
        "UnixTime":1405970056,
        "Human":"21 July 2014 19:14:16 GMT",
        "HumanDate":"21. Jul"
     },
     "Title":"An easy an enjoyable way to earn money",
     "Content":"Some message",
     "TrustScore":{
        "Score":100,
        "Stars":5,
        "Human":"Excellent",
        "StarsImageUrls":{
           "large":"//stars/l/5.png",
           "medium":"//stars/m/5.png",
           "small":"//stars/s/5.png"
        }
     },
     "CompanyReply":"",
     "User":{
        "Name":"Sofia Chinea",
        "City":null,
        "Locale":"en-GB",
        "ReviewCount":1,
        "IsVerified":false,
        "HasImage":false,
        "ImageUrls":{
           "i24":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/CloudImages/User/0/24x24.png",
           "i35":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/CloudImages/User/0/35x35.png",
           "i64":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/CloudImages/User/0/64x64.png",
           "i73":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/CloudImages/User/0/73x73.png"
        }
     },
     "Url":"http://www.example.com",
     "IsVerified":false
  },
}
```

Comment: why `var me = this;` instead of `var me = val;`?

Comment: I'm learning as I'm going and I put this snippet together from various sources so I might have mixed some code up. Wouldn't that be kind of the same thing though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your iterations:

```
  $.each(data.Reviews, function (key, val) {
      var me = this; // 'this' is the same as val

      $.each(val, function (i, j) { // you actually iterate over the 'me' variable here
          var stars = me.TrustScore.StarsImageUrls.small;
          var date = me.Created.HumanDate;
          var title = me.Title;
          var content = me.Content;
          var avatar = me.User.ImageUrls.i24;
          var name = me.User.Name;

          var block = '<div class="review">' +
              '<div class="stars"><img src="' + stars + '" class="stars" /></div>' +
              '<div class="date">' + date + '</div>' +
              '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
              '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' +
              '<p>' + content + '</p>' +
              '<div class="profile"><i><img src="' + avatar + '" /></i>' +
              '<span>' + name + '</span>' +
              '</div></div>';

          $(block).appendTo('#tp-body');
      });
    });
```

You see how you iterate over yourself.

Could you show an example of the data response you are getting so we can see what you are expecting to iterate over?

**EDIT**

It looks like you are iterating over each field of a Review on your 2nd loop, I don't quite know the purpose of the 2nd loop, I think you can just remove the loop and use the code inside that loop in your 1st loop. Like so:

```
  $.each(data.Reviews, function (key, val) {
      var me = this;

      var stars = me.TrustScore.StarsImageUrls.small;
      var date = me.Created.HumanDate;
      var title = me.Title;
      var content = me.Content;
      var avatar = me.User.ImageUrls.i24;
      var name = me.User.Name;

      var block = '<div class="review">' +
          '<div class="stars"><img src="' + stars + '" class="stars" /></div>' +
          '<div class="date">' + date + '</div>' +
          '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
          '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' +
          '<p>' + content + '</p>' +
          '<div class="profile"><i><img src="' + avatar + '" /></i>' +
          '<span>' + name + '</span>' +
          '</div></div>';

      $(block).appendTo('#tp-body');
  });
```

and to make that look abit better, since you are using the variables just once, it is quite useless to make variables of them:

```
  $.each(data.Reviews, function (key, val) {
      var block = '<div class="review">' +
          '<div class="stars"><img src="' + val.TrustScore.StarsImageUrls.small + '" class="stars" /></div>' +
          '<div class="date">' + val.Created.HumanDate + '</div>' +
          '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
          '<h3>' + val.Title + '</h3>' +
          '<p>' + val.Content + '</p>' +
          '<div class="profile"><i><img src="' + val.User.ImageUrls.i24 + '" /></i>' +
          '<span>' + val.User.Name + '</span>' +
          '</div></div>';

      $(block).appendTo('#tp-body');
  });
```

Comment: I added the response (edited) I get. There are obviously multiple reviews that I would like to go over and display.

Comment: It looks like you are iterating over each field of a Review on your 2nd loop, I don't quite know the purpose of the 2nd loop, I think you  can just remove the loop and use the code inside that loop in your 1st loop.

Comment: Okay I'll give that a try, although I think originally I received 'undefined' when I didn't have the second loop and trying to get anything inside Reviews.

Comment: Your first iteration is over the Reviews, so each `this` in that loop refers to a Review, hence only the first loop should be needed.

Comment: Okay so you were right. Removing the second loop works like it should and I don't have the duplicates. I don't understand though why it didn't work previously. Anyway. Thanks @JimmyKnoot

Comment: I don't know why either, but glad I could help :)